# Set class and data in HAML based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have some partial that looks like this:

```
.btn.btn-success{class: 'disabled',"data-original-title" => "Tooltip on left", "data-placement" => "left", "data-toggle" => "tooltip"}
  %span.fa.fa-gear
  Process
```

Is there possibility to refactor this template to set this:

```
{class: 'disabled',"data-original-title" => "Tooltip on left", "data-placement" => "left", "data-toggle" => "tooltip"}
```

only if for example 1+1 == 2?

I was trying almost everything but it not works...

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily

```
class: ('disabled' if  1 + 1 == 2), "data-original-title" => ("Tooltip on left" if  1 + 1 == 2), "data-placement" => ("left" if  1 + 1 == 2), "data-toggle" => ("tooltip" if  1 + 1 == 2)
```

Comment: This is easy when you have only class attribute, but I have more than one attribute and this will not work.

Comment: You can define a helper method according to your need, you just asked if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's an example to give the class active, depending controller and method:
You can use it to create your own.

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def is_active(controller, action)       
    params[:action] == action && params[:controller] == controller ? "active" : nil        
  end 
end
```

view file

```
 %li
   %a{class: is_active('controller_1', 'index'), :href => "/controller_1"}
```